Импортирование данныъ из одного файла js в другой
Я пишу серверную часть на JS и наткнулся на проблему с импортированием объекта из одного файла в другой.
Сама серверная часть
const express = require("express");
const { Client } = require("@notionhq/client");
const parser = require("body-parser");
const port = 3000;
const axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config();
const GetTableProperties = require("./GetTableProperties")


const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_KEY });
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
let newtask = {};




// разные маршрутизаторы

И есть метод в который я хочу импортировать Notion
async function GetTableProperties(notion) {
  const databaseId = process.env.NOTION_DATABASE;
  const response = await notion.databases.retrieve({
    database_id: databaseId,
  });
  let properties = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
  console.log(properties);  
  res.send(properties);
  return;
}
GetTableProperties()

module.exports = {GetTableProperties};

при передаче Notion как параметра функции, при импортировании с помощью module.exports и require выдаёт одну и ту же ошибку что с notion нельзя прочитать поля так как он undefined
если же напрямую в сервере прописать этот метод, то всё работает. то есть проблема лежит иммено в импортировании notion.

во втором листинге кода вызов GetTableProperties()

исправил. всё работает. изначально не заметил что написал

в методе куда импортировалась Notion,метод вызывал сам себя. стоит лишь удалить строку с вызовом метода
